# Can I reference the name of a property from an object in an other?

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I have the following objects:

```
var Foo = {
    propertyA: {
        subPropertyA : 10,
        subPropertyB : 'ABC'
    },
    propertyB: 'ABC'
}

var Bar = {
    propertyBar: 'propertyA'
}
```

But I'd like to set `propertyBar` by referencing `Foo`. Something like:

```
var Bar = {
    propertyBar:  Foo.propertyA.getKeyName()  // don't pay attention to syntax
}
```

And if I update the name of `propertyA` in `Foo`, the value of `propertyBar` will also be updated.

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by updating a property name?

Comment: @KingMob Well, if 'Foo' became something like `Foo { newPropertyA: /* ...*/ }` then `Bar.propertyBar` should be set to `newPropertyA`

Comment: Write a function to change Foo and Bar? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.How do you know that `newPropertyA` isn't just a new property? Maybe it would help if you described the bigger picture.

Answer (score -1):

You need to keep a reference of `Foo.propertyA` in 'Bar.propertyBar' something like this

```
var Bar = {
    propertyBar: Foo.propertyA
}
```

You can access it like `Bar.propertyBar.subPropertyA`

Comment: popertyBar should be set as "propertyA" (string), not the entire object, only the key.

Answer (score -1):

You need to keep a reference of `Foo.propertyA` in 'Bar.propertyBar' something like this

```
var Bar = {
    propertyBar: Foo.propertyA
}
```

You can access it like `Bar.propertyBar.subPropertyA`

If you dont want to keep the object then another way is use 'defineProperty'

```
var Foo = {
    propertyA: {
        subPropertyA : 10,
        subPropertyB : 'ABC'
    },
    propertyB: 'ABC'
}
var Bar = {};
Object.defineProperty(Bar, "propertyBar", { get: function () { return Foo.propertyA.subPropertyA ; } });
```